# Not catching exception when method withing the try is called?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, try-catch

Hi I'm calling some items from a web service and when they come back I create an interface tailored to the items returned inside of a seperate method. Now every time in a great while something goes wrong and I need to catch the exception and display a message to the user.

```
private void itemHelper_FeaturedItemsCalled(object sender, List<MyItem> _myItemList)
{
    try
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            if(_myItemList != 0)
                CreateInterface(_myItemList);
        });
    }
    catch
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            LoadingScreen.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            LoadingTextBlock.Text = "Unable to display items.";
            BusyIndicator1.IsRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I purposely threw an exception inside the method *CreateInterface()*. Now when this runs I get and unhandled exception. Why is that? I thought since the method was called inside of the try it would eventually get handled here?

Comment: A different thread is used to run the delegate that `BeginInvoke` invokes, so the exception is raised there and is unhandled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting the try catch inside the BeginInvoke. What is happening is that you are executing this code on a different thread so the exception is not caught by the differing thread.

Answer (score 7):

By calling `BeginInvoke` you're saying, "Execute this code in the dispatcher thread". `BeginInvoke` is asynchronous, so the whole method will probably complete before the code is executed - so how could it possibly go into the catch block? The calling thread will probably be in a completely different section of code by then.

It's *possible* that if you use `Invoke` instead of `BeginInvoke` you *might* get the exception marshalled back to the caller - but it's I can't see any evidence of that from the documentation.

EDIT: Additionally, even if you *had* managed to catch the exception, you'd be accessing the UI from the wrong thread at that point...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had an idea that BeginInvoke was the problem but now I know why. If I call the try/catch inside of BeginInvoke it catches the exception just fine.

Comment: @loyalpenguin: See my edit for an important extra point - the code you have in your catch block would need another Invoke/BeginInvoke call.

Comment: Yes excellent point. Sorry I was so busy trying to replace the original values that I deleted the second BeginInvoke. I'll fix it. I think by placing everything inside a single BeginInvoke I could remove that issue. I just hope there isn't a hit on resources by running everything inside of BeginInvoke...

Comment: @loyalpenguin: No, that should be fine - so long as you're not doing anything which should *really* be in a background thread. Note that the async stuff in C# 5 will make all of this a lot simpler.